# Laravel rand() exclude numbers

Tags: php, laravel

Mine code looks like:

```
$test = Hosting::where('status', 'active')->where('node', 'Full')->select('port')->get()->toArray();

while( in_array( ($n = mt_rand(1312,1319)), array($test) ) );
echo $n;
```

$test result is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "port" => 1315
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "port" => 1318
  ]
```

I want to exclude random numbers that is in $test result, now its(1315,1318), How would I do that?

Comment: You might be looking for [`array-diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php); it still better to exclude them from the query already.

Comment: What have you tried to make this work? What does `$test` contain?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `do while` here. I've also added [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) to get a flatten array of ports.

```php
$test = Hosting::where('status', 'active')
    ->where('node', 'Full')
    ->pluck('port')
    ->toArray();

do {
    $n = mt_rand(1312, 1319);
} while (in_array($n, $test));

echo $n;
```

I would advice to check for available ports before the loop to prevent an infinite loop, e.g.

```php
if (empty(array_diff(range(1312, 1319), $test))) {
    throw new \Exception('No port available.');
}
```

Comment: you can remove `select(...)->get()->pluck(...)` and replace those with just `pluck('port')` btw

Answer (score 0):

With Query Builder:

```
$hosts = Hosting::where('status', 'active')
    ->where('node', 'Full')
    ->select('port')
    ->whereNotIn('port' mt_rand(1312,1319))
    ->get();
```

With Eloquent Collection method:

```
$hosts = Hosting::where('status', 'active')
    ->where('node', 'Full')
    ->select('port')
    ->get()
    ->whereNotIn('port' mt_rand(1312,1319));
```

Comment: This commands bring collections result that not have the port numbers. But i want random numbers that is not saved in database. Means if save in db then search for another till you got a not noted numbed.